# Partitioning! how does hadoop make it? Use a hash function? what is the default function?

Tags: hadoop, hash, partitioning

Partitioning is the process of determining which reducer instance will receive which intermediate keys and values. Each mapper must determine for all of its output (key, value) pairs which reducer will receive them. It is necessary that for any key, regardless of which mapper instance generated it, the destination partition is the same
Problem: How does hadoop make it? Use a hash function? what is the default function?

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The default partitioner in Hadoop is the `HashPartitioner` which has a method called `getPartition`.  It takes `key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE` and finds the modulus using the number of reduce tasks.

For example, if there are 10 reduce tasks, `getPartition` will return values 0 through 9 for all keys.

Here is the code:

```
public class HashPartitioner<K, V> extends Partitioner<K, V> {
    public int getPartition(K key, V value, int numReduceTasks) {
        return (key.hashCode() & Integer.MAX_VALUE) % numReduceTasks;
    }
}
```

To create a custom partitioner, you would extend `Partitioner`, create a method `getPartition`, then set your partitioner in the driver code (`job.setPartitionerClass(CustomPartitioner.class);`).  This is particularly helpful if doing secondary sort operations, for example.

Comment: @tommy_o How is getPartition(..) method called ? What calls this method? where to call this method?

Comment: @BurakKarasoy when you create a Job object to configure the MR job properties, it will provide you a method to declare CustomPartitioner if any as specified by author above. This custom partitioner gets invoked internally to MR framework after the Map task has completed and the data is getting spilled on to the disk