# How do I set the numReduceTask for custom Partitioner in the case of custom key

Tags: java, hadoop, mapreduce

```
HashPartitioner<Text,Text> hash=new HashPartitioner<Text,Text>();

@Override
public int getPartition(CompositeKeyClass keyClass, Text valClass, int numOfPartition) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    try {       
        String[] type=valClass.toString().split(",");

        if(type[0].equals("Mapper1")) {
            return (hash.getPartition(keyClass.getFirst(), valClass, numOfPartition))%numOfPartition;
        } else {
            return (hash.getPartition(keyClass.getFirst(), valClass, numOfPartition))%numOfPartition;   
        }
    }
}
```

I am using the above code in the Partitioner class to get the key for my custom class. All works fine but I want that the value that has the text "Mapper1" sent to first reducer and the other one sent to second. How can I achieve that? I have set `job.numOfReduceTaks` to 2. Please help!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a static decision right?
Try this:

```
if (type[0].equals("Mapper1")) {
    return 0;
} else {
    return 1;
}
```

And yes, in driver you need to set `job.numOfReduceTaks` to 2. You did it right.

Comment: How can I return the getPartition method then? It needs to be returned with the key class in order to send the proper key to reducer.

Comment: @AmardeepSingh Well I am not getting perhaps what you want to say. Your getPartition() method simply needs to return an int (i.e. 0<=partition number < numPartitionNumber). What HashPartitioner does is, it takes the hash of your key and performs some logical operation like AND(with Integer.MAX_VALUE) and modulo operation on it for uniform distribution. For more look here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470833/partitioning-how-does-hadoop-make-it-use-a-hash-function-what-is-the-default

Comment: Basically i am using a Custom Partitioner for a Custom Key class. The following code works if there is just one Reducer. How do I set to so that it can handle the case when I need two reducers? inline ' public static class partition extends Partitioner<CompositeKey, Text>
 {
  
  private HashPartitioner<Text,Text> hash=new HashPartitioner<Text,Text>();

  @Override
  public int getPartition(CompositeKey key, Text val, int num) {
 
   return hash.getPartition(key.getFirst(), val, num)%num;
  }
  
 } '