# Can a reducer dynamically make use of multiple nodes?

Tags: hadoop, mapreduce

While writing code for MapReduce jobs, if we set the number of reducers manually, it is possible that the data sent to a certain reducer is large. In such a case, can the reducer task run on multiple nodes at once? Perhaps by dividing the data in the `List<Value>` corresponding to a key, and later merging internally?

If a reducer can not autoscale the number of nodes it is to use, then how do we take care of conditions where we may have an unequal distribution of values corresponding to keys? The [default hadoop MapReduce partitioner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18470833/partitioning-how-does-hadoop-make-it-use-a-hash-function-what-is-the-default) partitions on the basis of the value of the hash, and does not take into account the size of `List<Value>` corresponding to the key.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, a reducer does not auto-scale. If its workload is too heavy, it will crash.

The best you can do (probably) is write your own custom partitioner that distributes the workload evenly among the reducers. Doing that is not always easy, as you may have to do a sampling or estimation of the data, or even an extra counting job, and write a decent load balancing algorithm satisfying the needs of your problem.

What you want, may not be to distribute the load based on the size of the values per key, but based on the computations that the reducers will perform (those two are not always the same).

Comment: Okay, but two things. 1. Is it possible to define the percentage of node resources which would be allocated to the reducer then? 2. If we must set the number of reducers manually in a certain case, then what can be done to mitigate the problem of overburdening certain reducers?

Comment: @DhruvMullick I am afraid I don't have an answer for 1. Regarding 2., if you don't want a sampling, you can manually set a custom partitioner that assigns the keys you expect to have the heaviest load to a reducer of their own (i.e., no other keys should go to the same reducer). For example, in WordCount send all the words starting from the most frequent letter (e.g., letter 's') to a reducer of their own and all other words in random.